# printf usage with awk when printing multiple columns

Tags: awk

I am trying this below command:

```
cat dcl1serrfip_check.csv | grep -Fi 'BANK0_F5_WRDAT_P0[0]' | grep -i setup | grep 'L2H' | grep highv | grep -i low | awk -F ',' -v dev="0.861" -v rc="1.105" -v inte="0.872" '{ print ($10+$11)-(($12+$13)-($14))","($10*dev)+($11*rc)-(($12*dev)+($13*rc)-($14*inte))}'
```

This gives below output:

```
-6.93889e-18,0.000288
```

I want this output to be formatted to 4 decimal places. How to do it? The desired output would be

```
-0.0000,0.0002
```

Comment: `0.000288 = 0.0002`  ? it will become `0.0003`

Answer (score 1):

You need, `%0.4f` or `%.4f`

To Test use :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ printf("%0.4f\n", -6.93889e-18) }'
```

So it becomes:

```
printf("%0.4f,%0.4f\n", ($10+$11)-(($12+$13)-($14)), ($10*dev)+($11*rc)-(($12*dev)+($13*rc)-($14*inte)) )
```

Actually you can rewrite your command in `awk` itself, no need of so many `grep` and `cat` combination

Comment: How can I give it along with the above command I mentioned? I need two fields to be formatted like this at the same time

Comment: cat dcl1serrfip_check.csv | grep -Fi 'BANK0_F5_WRDAT_P0[0]' | grep -i setup | grep 'L2H' | grep highv | grep -i low | awk -F ',' -v dev="0.861" -v rc="1.105" -v inte="0.872" '{ printf "%0.4f,%0.4f\n", ($10+$11)-(($12+$13)-($14))","($10*dev)+($11*rc)-(($12*dev)+($13*rc)-($14*inte))}'
This doesnt work. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Manus: please copy once again and paste it properly, replace your `print ....` with what I have given